# Statistics / Regression Question

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics

So I am writing an econ paper and will be using regressions. I have written  my intro / lit review / collected relevant data. I have Swiss quarterly and yearly export data by industry from 2009-2018. In 2015, the Swiss National Bank removed its fixed exchange rate (was pegged to the euro)… I am interested in measuring the effect of large sudden currency appreciation which occurred after the depeg. I have all my data, and ultimately just want to estimate the impact using pre and post depeg data. I am not entirely sure how to build my model (I am not a great statistician or econometrician). I know that export levels will be my dependent variable, and exchange rate will be in my explanatory. Would simple linear be sufficient? Would RDD be appropriate? How would I incorporate a depeg dummy variable into my model if my only explanatory is exchange rate – would this present multicollinearity problem? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does export level look like? Is it continuous or categorical? Does it have upper and/or lower bounds?

Comment: Continuous data. For example, from Q1 2008 to Q4 2018, organic chemicals export sales range from 4bn francs to 5.8bn francs. I want to run a regression for Sqitzerlands largest 25 products / industries. Would OLS be the best way to analyze effect of the depeg?

Answer (score 1):

A simple linear regression would not be appropriate as each observation (i.e. a quarter in a given year) is not independent of the other observations and they are also ordered.

A regression discontinuity design would also struggle due to the time series nature of your data... What you are probably after would be a time-series model as this accounts for the autocorrelation between observations and would allow you to account for cyclic variation in the data (See [this link](https://www.reed.edu/economics/parker/312/tschapters/S13_Ch_1.pdf)). There is approaches which are an amalgamation of both time series and RDD ([RDiT / ES](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b53a/eaa65c169cc19aeb121d62387ff0d27f15ca.pdf)) which you could also explore, although I am not sure how easy they are to implement.

Comment: Just came across this when looking at something completely unrelated but it sounds like the same kind of problem in a completely different subject area - https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b53a/eaa65c169cc19aeb121d62387ff0d27f15ca.pdf